# In listview changing background of button in rows on click of button in one row

Tags: android

I have a listview with play button to play songs in each row. When i click on play button its background changes to pause button. What i want is when I click on play button in one row, the button that has background set to pause image on previous click should automatically change to play image and only the button which I has clicked should have pause background. 
On click of button in a row of listview how to change other rows buttons background?

Regards,
Naresh T

Comment: in your `BaseAdapter` implementation get array of background and change the background for item `i` on clicked. then you'll have any background you want for any button, at index i...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give you the basic idea of how you could implement this. You need to have a custom `Adapter` which would store the `View` which is currently set to "playing" state. Let's say, it would be called `mCurPlaying`. After the user clicks another `View`, change the background of the `mCurPlaying` and replace it with the newly clicked `View`.

Should you have any problems with implementing this, please, drop a note and I'll give you some more hints in code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing on click for whole row set only onclick for a button in that row in getview method of adapter class it solved your problem.